# using templateUrl inside angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, web-frontend

try to use directive to return templateUrl html i did same way angularjs documentation but still gives me a plain white page at simple point was working and then stop render  templateUrl  part and i have not clue what i did wrong

```
<!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myform" ng-cloak>
<div layout="row" flex layout-align="center center">
    <div my-step1></div>
</div>
 <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">     </script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-    material.min.js"></script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

javascript(app.js)

```
var form = angular.module('myform', ['ngMaterial','ngAnimate','ngMessages', 'ngRoute']);
         form.directive('myStep1', function () {
          return {
               templateUrl: 'my-step1.html'
               };
            });
```

my-step1.html

```
<div><h1> ng directive works fine  </h1> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- the `<script>` tags should be inside the `<head>` tag, not the `<body>` tag
- there's a space in `angular-    material.min.js`
- check the console, modules are not loaded properly; load **angular.js** instead of angular.**min**.js to have a useful error message

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with your directive, but in the order of referencing your script files. Now

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

And because your **myform** module depends on angular material, so you have to reference it before like following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```